# How can I avoid all this code duplication?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

As you can see I have to populate the ViewModel with the List of Tags so that the dropdown can have all the options for the user to select.
And I have to do this 2 times for the Create Action and 2 times for the Edit action.

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var tags = from i in _articleService.GetAllTags()
               select new SelectListItem {Text = i.Name, Value = i.ID.ToString()};
    var model = new CreateArticleViewModel {Tags = tags};
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost, Authorize]
public ActionResult Create(CreateArticleViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            var currentUser = _userService.GetByUserName(User.Identity.Name);
            var tagIds = model.TagIds.Select(int.Parse);
            var article = _articleService.Create(currentUser, model.Title, model.Body, tagIds);
            return RedirectToAction("ViewArticle", new { id = article.ID });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Error", ex.Message);
        }
    }
    var tags = from i in _articleService.GetAllTags()
               select new SelectListItem { Text = i.Name, Value = i.ID.ToString() };
    model.Tags = tags;
    return View(model);
}

[Authorize]
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{

    var article = _articleService.GetById(id);
    var tags = from tag in _articleService.GetAllTags().ToList()
               select new SelectListItem { Text = tag.Name, Value = tag.ID.ToString(), Selected = article.HasTag(tag)};
    var model = new CreateArticleViewModel {Title=article.Title, Body = article.Body, Tags = tags };


    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost, Authorize]
public ActionResult Edit(CreateArticleViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            //handle article update
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Add ModelState error 
        }
    }
    var tags = from tag in _articleService.GetAllTags().ToList()
               select new SelectListItem { Text = tag.Name, Value = tag.ID.ToString(), Selected = article.HasTag(tag)};
    model.Tags= tags;

    return View(model);
}
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

You could refactor out your tagging into a helper method, as below:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Create()
{
   var model = new CreateArticleViewModel {};
   TagModel (model, _ => false);
   return View(model);
}
[HttpPost, Authorize]
public ActionResult Create(CreateArticleViewModel model)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      try
      {
         var currentUser = _userService.GetByUserName(User.Identity.Name);
         var tagIds = model.TagIds.Select(int.Parse);
         var article = _articleService.Create(currentUser, model.Title, model.Body, tagIds);
         return RedirectToAction("ViewArticle", new { id = article.ID });
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
         ModelState.AddModelError("Error", ex.Message);
      }
   }
   TagModel (model, _ => false);
   return View(model);
}

[Authorize]
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
   var article = _articleService.GetById(id);
   var model = new CreateArticleViewModel {Title=article.Title, Body = article.Body};
   TagModel (model, tag => article.HasTag (tag));

   return View(model);
}

[HttpPost, Authorize]
public ActionResult Edit(CreateArticleViewModel model)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      try
      {
            //handle article update
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
            //Add ModelState error 
      }
   }
   TagModel (model, tag => article.HasTag (tag));
   return View(model);
}

private void TagModel (CreateArgicleViewModel model, Predicate<Tag> isSelected)
{
   var tags = from tag in _articleService.GetAllTags()
              select new SelectListItem { Text = tag.Name, Value = tag.ID.ToString(), Selected = isSelected(tag)};
   model.Tags= tags;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Recently I've been reading a great series of blog posts by [Ayende Rahien](http://ayende.com) discussing how we can limit abstractions in a code base and how to implement a very simple infrastructure to make an abstraction for code reuse.
Take a look at one of the posts of these series [here](http://ayende.com/blog/154209/limit-your-abstractions-refactoring-toward-reduced-abstractions). You can find the rest of them on his blog.

Comment: great series of blogposts... I dont see how it relates to my question though.

Comment: You can use Query abstraction to run a predefined query to get all the tags